# Django failed to insert record into session after login

Tags: python, sql-server, django

```
Django failed to insert record into session after login with message:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError at /admin/
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.', None, 0, -2147217913), None)

Command:
INSERT INTO [django_session] ([session_key], [session_data], [expire_date]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)

Parameters:
[Name: p0, Dir.: Input, Type: adBSTR, Size: 32, Value: "orctnepzkaqb4haa6tn7jjit961a4l3s", Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0, Name: p1, Dir.: Input, Type: adBSTR, Size: 60, Value: "M2FiMTM4NGJmNjY4NDc2YjA0Y2I1ZjI4NDcxYzNlNTExYTljODYxMTp7fQ==", Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0, Name: p2, Dir.: Input, Type: adBSTR, Size: 26, Value: "2014-12-30T12:38:53.076000", Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you look at the date of 2014-12-30T12: 38: 53.076000 shows that the milliseconds are composed of 6 digits.

Direct insert to a database with the same parameters returns the same error of conversion.

If you truncate milliseconds up to 3 characters, the insertion will occur normally.

Where and when is the django creates a date in this format?

This error occurs only on a production environment.
Python 2.7, Django 1.6.8, OS: Windows Server 2008R2, web server: IIS 7, DB Server: MS SQL 2008R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS not solve the problem because "now" function from the "timezone" returns time with microseconds.
I made changes to the function:

```
   if settings.USE_TZ:
        # timeit shows that datetime.now(tz=utc) is 24% slower
        return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc, microsecond=0)
    else:
        return datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try by settings `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` in your settings.py

[**more in docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats)

try something like:

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',   
)
```